# How to fire an event when click occurs in iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, iframe

I want to catch clicks that occur anywhere in an iframe. I can not directly access the iframe because it contains content from another domain. So how would I do that with jQuery? Somehow calculate if the click occurred in the area of the iframe? The iframe should stay totally accessible as it contains links etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible due to the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). jQuery cannot magically circumvent the browser environment.

You may wish to implement a [same-domain proxy](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html) (example in php) that passes the target site's html through to your iframe. You didn't mention what server-side technology you are using so I cannot be more specific.

Comment: But what about tracking mouse movement and telling whether it is over the iframe. You don't need to access the iframe for that, do you?

Comment: Correct, you don't need the iframe's DOM to track mouse movements over it. However you specifically say in your question: "iframe should stay totally accessible". I take that to mean you cannot intercept events overtop of the iframe and need them to actually hit the iframe.