# click event does not work on iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add click event to a iframe with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609741/how-to-add-click-event-to-a-iframe-with-jquery)

I am trying to add a click event to my iframe but it does not seem to work?

code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#iframe_id').bind('click', function (event) { alert('hi'); });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <iframe id="iframe_id" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Click events on iframes are captured by the iframes themselves and not the parent window nodes. So the `<iframe>` doesn't receive the click, the `<body>` of it does.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170698/track-clicks-inside-iframe-with-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803251/jquery-click-tracking-not-working-on-iframe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499664/how-to-fire-an-event-when-click-occurs-in-iframe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708969/how-to-add-a-click-event-to-p-elements-in-iframe-using-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680778/click-event-in-iframe

Comment: @tekknolagi: it would be awesome if you posted all those links in one comment...

Comment: @JCOC611 sorry; found them over a span of a few minutes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329832/how-to-make-iframe-listen-to-click-event-of-parent-iframe-and-use-the-path-of-th
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472550/detect-click-inside-iframe
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305276/create-an-iframe-on-button-click-with-jquery

Comment: @JCOC611 there; got a few in one comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.document.body.onclick = 
function() {
  alert("iframe clicked");
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Unsafe, and therefore does not work on many browsers.

Comment: **Note:** the iframe's content MUST be from your domain!